# Performance difference of rolling window aggregations for frame global and window local transformations

Tags: python, python-polars

I am observing a "puzzling" performance difference on the following two equivalent window aggregation implementations.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

rng = np.random.default_rng()
date = [t.date() for t in pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2023-12-31", freq="B")]    
ids = [f"id_{i+1}" for i in range(1000)]
ids, date = zip(*itertools.product(ids, date))
values = np.expm1(0.01 * rng.normal(size=len(date)))

frame = polars.from_dict({"id": ids, "date": date, "value": values}).lazy()

t0 = time.time()
frame.select(
    pl.col("id"),
    pl.col("date"),
    pl.col("value").log1p().alias("log_value")
).sort(
    by=["id", "date"]
).rolling(
    index_column="date", by="id", period=datetime.timedelta(days=30)
).agg(
    pl.col("log_value").sum()
).select(
    pl.col("id"),
    pl.col("date"),
    np.expm1(pl.col("log_value")).alias("result")
).collect()
t = time.time() - t0
print(f"Time for aggregation with frame global `log1p` and `expm1` is {t=:.3f}s.")
>>> Time for aggregation with frame global `log1p` and `expm1` is t=0.209s.

t0 = time.time()
frame.rolling(
    index_column="date", by="id", period=datetime.timedelta(days=30)
).agg(
    np.expm1(pl.col("value").log1p().sum())
).collect()
t = time.time() - t0
print(f"Time for aggregation with window local `log1p` and `expm1` is {t=:.3f}s.")
>>> Time for aggregation with window local `log1p` and `expm1` is t=0.119s.
```

I'd have expected the version using a 'frame global' way of transforming values of to be (a lot faster) compared to the version that transforms for each window. But in fact the latter is almost twice as fast.

It'd be great if someone could explain this - it is actually a lot more convenient to use the second version, because the expression for the aggregation is completely located within the `rolling` block.

Comment: The first version has a `.sort()` and if you are timing both of these in the same "interactive session" there will be caching involved. If I remove the `.sort()` and time both from a "cold start" (i.e. save the frame to disk and use `.scan_parquet()` in 2 separate files) the runtime is pretty much identicial.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great catch with the additional `sort` call.